# Python - permission denied remotely

Tags: python, ssh, permission-denied

I'm using a program called SPAdes-3.50-Darwin and while running it on a server (one which I do not have root access to), I get the following error even though on my local computer it runs fine:

```
   == Running read error correction tool: /export/home/james/Tools/SPAdes-3.5.0-Darwin/bin/hammer /export/home/james/package/output/pg/assembly_files/NA12877_S1_chr14_105900000-107300000/spades_files/3-49/corrected/configs/config.info 

  [Errno 13] Permission denied
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/home/james/Tools/SPAdes-3.5.0-Darwin/bin/spades.py", line 586, in main
  ext_python_modules_home, log)
  File "/export/home/james/Tools/SPAdes-3.5.0-Darwin/share/spades/spades_pipeline/hammer_logic.py", line 128, in run_hammer
   support.sys_call(command, log)
  File "/export/home/james/Tools/SPAdes-3.5.0-Darwin/share/spades/spades_pipeline/support.py", line 181, in sys_call
  proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
 errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Does this have to do with not having root permission?

Comment: Quite possibly the binary that your application is trying to call doesn't have the execution bit set?  Check the contents of `cmd_list` and `cwd` and try to resolve the binary that is being called on the server's filesystem.

Comment: If I don't have the ability to change the execution bit set, is there a way to have the process call a local version of /usr/lib/python2.7?

Comment: Update your question to include the contents of `cmd_list` and `cwd` and the permission associated with them.  Though you may also want to check the permissions set on `/export/home/james/Tools/SPAdes-3.5.0-Darwin/bin/hammer` itself as per error message.  And yes, you can have the process call any binary for your `subprocess.Popen` call.